# How to visually animate Markov chains in Python?

Tags: python, animation, networkx, simulation, markov-chains

I want to "visually" animate Markov chains like here : http://markov.yoriz.co.uk/ but using Python instead of html css and javascript.

I don't know if there is any library that makes this easy, till now I managed to make a visual representation of Markov chains using Networkx library like in the figure below, but couldn't get it to be animated (or simulated)

Here is my code so far:

```
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import write_dot
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

states = [(0, 0),
          (1, 0),
          (2, 0),]


Q = [[5, 5, 0.4],
     [1, 2, 3],
     [4, 0.7, 0]
     ]


G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
labels={}
edge_labels={}

for i, origin_state in enumerate(states):
    for j, destination_state in enumerate(states):
        rate = Q[i][j]
        if rate > 0:
            G.add_edge(origin_state, destination_state, weight=rate, label="{:.02f}".format(rate))
            edge_labels[(origin_state, destination_state)] = label="{:.02f}".format(rate)



plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
node_size = 200
pos = {state:list(state) for state in states}
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,width=1.0,alpha=0.5)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_weight=2)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels)
plt.axis('off');
plt.show()

write_dot(G, 'mc.dot')

from subprocess import check_call
nfile = 'w.png' 
check_call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'mc.dot', '-o', nfile])

import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img = mpimg.imread(nfile)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Take a look a this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66496889/how-can-i-make-matplotlib-animation-that-uses-networkx-much-faster

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by sampling from your Markov chain over a certain number of steps (100 in the code below) and modifying the color of the selected node at each step (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814640/color-a-particular-node-in-networkx-and-graphviz) on how to change color of the nodes with graphviz).
You can then create a png file of your network for each step and use imageio to generate a GIF from the png images (see more details on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python)).

Below is the full code:

```py
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph
import numpy as np
import imageio

#Markov chain parameters
states = [(0, 0),
          (1, 0),
          (2, 0),]


Q = [[0.2, 0.3, 0.5],
     [0.1, 0.2, 0.7],
     [0.3, 0.7, 0]
     ]

#Sampling the markov chain over 100 steps
N_steps=100
node_ind=0
node_sel=[node_ind]
for i in range(N_steps):
  temp_ni=np.random.choice(3,p=Q[node_ind])
  node_sel.append(temp_ni)
  node_ind=temp_ni

#Setting up network
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
[G.add_node(s,style='filled',fillcolor='white',shape='circle',fixedsize='true',width=0.5) for s in states]

labels={}
edge_labels={}

for i, origin_state in enumerate(states):
    for j, destination_state in enumerate(states):
        rate = Q[i][j]
        if rate > 0:
            G.add_edge(origin_state, destination_state, weight=rate, label="{:.02f}".format(rate),len=2)

#Setting up node color for each iteration     
for k in range(N_steps):
  for i,n in enumerate(G.nodes(data=True)):
    if i==node_sel[k]:
      n[1]['fillcolor']='blue'
    else:
      n[1]['fillcolor']='white'
    
  A = to_agraph(G)
  A.layout()
  A.draw('net_'+str(k)+'.png')

#Create gif with imageio
images = []
filenames=['net_'+str(k)+'.png' for k in range(N_steps)]
for filename in filenames:
    images.append(imageio.imread(filename))
imageio.mimsave('markov_chain.gif', images,fps=3)
```

And here is the result:

[image]