# How can I make matplotlib animation that uses networkx much faster?

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, networkx

the code below runs a function (showNet) 100 times. The function takes in a list of node-labels to update the network figure.
Now, the code takes about 16.55 sec to complete, meaning that each of the 100 frames/figures-updates took 16.55 / 100 = 0.16 sec. Which is less than my needs.

My question is, is there any way I can make this much faster? I am aware that there are some solutions like multiprocessing or blit, but I honestly don't know how to use them in matplotlib.

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import time


global ax, fig, G
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
G = nx.DiGraph()

def showNet(n):
    global ax, fig, G

    plt.style.use('Solarize_Light2')
    
    fig.clf()    

    l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7 = n[0], n[1], n[2], n[3], n[4], n[5], n[6] 

    edgelist= [(l1,l2),(l2,l3), (l3,l4), (l3,l5), (l4, l1), (l5, l6), (l5, l7)]

    pos = {l1: (10, 60), l2: (10, 40), l3:(80, 40), l4:(140, 60), l5:(200, 20), l6:(250, 40), l7:(250,10)}
    
    ax = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, nodelist=list(pos.keys()), node_size=2000, alpha=1) 
    ax = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, edgelist= edgelist , edge_color="gray", arrows=True, arrowsize=10, arrowstyle='wedge') 

    ax = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos, labels=dict(zip(pos.keys(),pos.keys())),  font_color="black") 
    
    # Hide grid lines
    plt.grid(False)

    plt.ion() 
    fig.show() 
    plt.pause(0.0000001)


start = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(100):
    n = random.sample(range(1, 10), 7)
    showNet(n)

finish = time.perf_counter()
print(finish - start)
```

Comment: If you are only updating the node names, you maybe better of drawing the graph layout first, then update the text only. Also have a look at Animation.

Comment: yes, I think that the only things I can do outside of the function are the figure and the Graph variable (G), which I just did (see the code I just edited it). But still, not a significant difference. the previous timing (when G was created inside the function) was 16.55 sec, now that G is outside the function, the timing is 16.1 sec. Any idea how to make use of multiprocessing in matplotlib like my case? thanks.

Comment: No, all those `ax = nx.draw_network...` inside the functions that are costly. `G=nx.DiGraph()` is nothing.

Comment: Why is this not fast enough?  If you're drawing in real time, then clearly multiprocessing won't help.

Comment: @QuangHoang Can you show me how you would do that if you tried and it worked because when I tried it, the figure didn't show at all.

Comment: @TimRoberts I need it to be as fast as it can be for a certain project I am working on. Well, since multiprocessing won't work, is there any other alternative? I've heard of "blit" but still didn't try it out. I might update the code if I ever managed to do it.

Comment: "Fast as it can be" -- do you understand that's a pointless phrase?  If you wanted it "fast as it can be", you wouldn't be writing it in Python.  What's your spec?  How fast does it need to be?

Comment: I think I've been so clear: what I meant is ! if there was any way the function I posted can be even faster, please do show me how. Like the suggestions from Mr. Quang for example, they were pretty helpful indeed. if there isn't a way (in Python lf course) then tell me that there isn't and that also would be helpful so I won't be spending more time. (Sorry if there is any misunderstanding as I am newbie to Python and in Stackoverflow too)